# Use .bib file to add bibliography to markdown document

Tags: markdown, wiki, pandoc

I would like to add references to a github wiki from a `.bib` file. So I need to produce a markdown file with the embedded bibliography.

I usually convert `markdown + .bib` to pdf, html or doc using [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/). For example:

```
pandoc test.md --bibliography allBib.bib -t markdown -o out.html
```

**Is it possible to output a file that correspond to the input markdown file with the references replaced from the `.bib` file?**

I tried

```
pandoc Experimental-notes.md --bibliography ../allBib.bib -t markdown -o out.md
```

but the resulting markdown file is not changed and does not contain the references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1161832/471587): you need to remove the `citations` extension from the output format.

```
pandoc Experimental-notes.md -t markdown-citations -o out.md --bibliography ../allBib.bib
```